# Rails 4 form_for name issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

guys haw I can set special name to my **rails form** ??

I'm tried to use this command but it always fail

```
<%= form_for(@contact,:name =>"FormContact", :remote => true)   do |f| %>
```

OR

```
<%= form_for(:FormContact,@contact, :remote => true)   do |f| %>
```

OR

```
<%= form_for(@contact,name: "FormContact", :remote => true)   do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= form_for(@contact, html: { name: "FormContact" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Hope it helps :)